# why my app vibrate constantly?

Tags: android

I used vibrate service in android and set duration = 500ms as below

```
Vibrator v = (Vibrator) this.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);        

long milliseconds = 500;

v.vibrate(milliseconds);
```

Sometimes it worked OK but sometimes i don't know why it vibrate constantly and only stop when i turn on the screen.
My app works on android 2.2.

Please help me.

Thanks a lot.

/*******Edit********/

thanks for your replies,

I start vibrating inside an alarm service. Every time alarm goes off, i will play a sound and start vibrating inside this service. Here is my code

```
Vibrator v = (Vibrator) this.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
long milliseconds = 500;
v.vibrate(milliseconds);

MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.normal);
mp.start();
mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
  public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mp.release();
    }
});
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
mWakelock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK
            | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "AlarmScreen");
mWakelock.acquire(120000);
```

the matter is that sometimes it works ok, but sometimes it vibrates constantly and only stop when i turn on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use in a such way...

```
    Vibrator v = (Vibrator)getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    v.vibrate(2000);
```

Remove:

```
    this.
```

and everything gonna be alright

Comment: 'this' here is service object itself. i don't think this is the matter of my problem.

Comment: thanks you, but i got exception IllegalStateException when i call mp.release() before mp.start()

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't the code you're using to vibrate the devices, it's probably the code that's calling the vibration. I'm guessing you're in some sort of loop that's triggering the vibration. Can you show the code used to start vibrating?

Answer (score 0):

You can force stop the vibration using the delay

```
final Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
v.vibrate(2000);

final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
    //Do something after 2000ms (avoid random vibrations)
    v.cancel();
    }
}, 2000);
```